# Append Data to Pandas from Different Site

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Im trying to append the data to Pandas DataFrame from different URL, however it seems like the loop is not working. Do anybody have any Idea how to do this.
Just an additional Info, the web will change the url on next using numbers.

```
import requests
import pandas
import numpy
import re
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#### page info ###
for k in range (1,3):
    k=str(k)
    page = requests.get("https://postcode.my/search/?keyword=&state=Kedah&page="+k)
#### check page status (will come 200 if the page is ok) 
    page.status_code
### call Library
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
### Find rows 
    rows = soup.find_all(class_="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12")
## create list by append
    L=[]
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all("td")
        cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        L.append(cols)
## convert to numpy array and reshape to 4 columns 
        cols = ['LOCATION','AREA','STATE','POSTCODE']
        PDTABLE = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(L).reshape(-1,4),columns = cols)
        print(PDTABLE)
        ##PDTABLE.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Thank You
Best Regards
Railey Shahril

Comment: The code works fine? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi, 
Yes the code work fine, however if you uncomment the ##PDTABLE.to_csv('test.csv') it will only pick the last loop data and it not appended. event the PDTABLE are shown as two separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign variables inside a loop it will get replaced when second loop runs.

Try:

```
import requests
import pandas
import numpy
import re
import csv

L = []

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#### page info ###
for k in range (1,3):
    k=str(k)
    page = requests.get("https://postcode.my/search/?keyword=&state=Kedah&page="+k)
#### check page status (will come 200 if the page is ok) 
    page.status_code
### call Library
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
### Find rows 
    rows = soup.find_all(class_="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12")
## create list by append

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all("td")
        cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        L.append(cols)

## convert to numpy array and reshape to 4 columns 
cols = ['LOCATION','AREA','STATE','POSTCODE']
PDTABLE = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(L).reshape(-1,4),columns = cols)
PDTABLE.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you the code is working fine, 
I need to learn more about this and try to understand the code line by line